# Missing data (multiple imputation)

Tags: multiple-imputation

Can I multiply impute missing data in some of the 
variables which were for some reason not measured at one time?

For 
instance, for production I have time series data for 1961-2011: however, some of
the predictor variables (rainfall, temperature, humidity and few more) which 
I suspect could have impact on rice production of Nepal were measured only after 1975. So the data for 1961-1974 are missing!

Could multiple imputation help in this case, or is there any other option?

Comment: The key question in return is what you would use to impute your missing data here. Missing climate data would best be imputed through some relation with other climate data, possibly a neighbouring area in India if some relation can be found. Pitfalls here include the possibility that the climate is changing; that quite different relationships may be involved over 1961 to 2011, e.g. Green Revolution, new crop varieties etc.; respecting any dependence structure in the climate data.

Comment: Many thanks for this, Nick. I am stuck. I have no idea how i whoud hava a break through here.